# Favicon not showing up. Even after cache cleared + browser restart

Tags: html, favicon

said page located here:

http://lolisrael.co.il/betatest/index.php

favicon is located here:

http://lolisrael.co.il/betatest/favicon.ico?v=3

I've cleared the history, and reloaded the page and it still shows no favicon

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://lolisrael.co.il/betatest/favicon.ico?v=3" />
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to have query string `v=3` ?

Comment: I was reading up on it, and it said v = version, and changing it to a different number would refresh it and make it appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `<script>` tag containing facebook code is manipulating DOM. And if you inspect with developer tools in Chrome, you can see that in the final DOM tree, your `<link rel="shortcut icon"` is put in `<body>`.

Try moving the facebook code into `<body>`. According to [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1):

> You should insert it **directly after the opening `<body>` tag** on each page you want to load it:

Comment: i did that! Still no result. however it still puts it into my body. Nevermind, I put it before all the stylesheets and that seemed to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

That `<link>` tag goes in the `<head>` not the `<body>`. It should work once you move it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Favicon Checker](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=http%3A%2F%2Flolisrael.co.il%2Fbetatest%2Findex.php#.VBEOTC6Sw9Y), your ICO is corrupted. Lots of other problems detected too.

Errors are as follow:

> favicon.ico seems corrupted or not in ICO format.
>
> Some picture(s) are missing in favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

For me when trying with localhost it is working. Are you sure that you have valid image in the .ico format. If no please regenerate the ico file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sir. This code is working for me.

```
 <link rel="icon" href="http://lolisrael.co.il/betatest/favicon.ico?v=3" type="image/x-icon">
```